# proof that $ \lim_{x \to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{x})^x=e$ from the sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Let be $a_n=(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ the sequence that has $e$ as limit

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}  (1+\frac{1}{n})^n=e$$

I'm trying to understand the proof that

$$ \lim_{x \to +\infty}  (1+\frac{1}{x})^x=e$$

in which x is a real number.

In the first part, it says that $a_n$ is an increasing sequence and it tends towards $e$.

**As a consequence,
$$\forall  \varepsilon >0  \exists \nu \in N  \ni \not \forall n>\nu : |f(n)-e|< \varepsilon  \Longrightarrow e- \varepsilon<(1+\frac{1}{n})^n<e$$**

1) I tried to justify this last sentence thinking that:

$$|(1+\frac{1}{n})^n-e|< \varepsilon \Longrightarrow - \varepsilon <(1+\frac{1}{n})^n-e< + \varepsilon \Longrightarrow e - \varepsilon <(1+\frac{1}{n})^n< e + \varepsilon \Longrightarrow e - \varepsilon <(1+\frac{1}{n})^n< e$$ **Is it right?**

2)**It says also that we can assume  $\nu>\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$.Why $\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$?**

Then the proof follow in this way:

Let be $x> \nu + 1$ , and $[x]$ be its integer part $\Longrightarrow [x]>\nu$ and $(1+\frac{1}{[x]+1})^{[x]}<(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x}<(1+\frac{1}{[x]})^{[x]+1}$

3)**I've thought that if $x> \nu +1$, $[x]> \nu$, $[x]+1>x>[x]$ and then:
$(1+\frac{1}{[x]+1})^{[x]}<(1+\frac{1}{[x]})^{[x]}<(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x}<(1+\frac{1}{[x]+1})^{[x]+1}<(1+\frac{1}{[x]})^{[x]+1}$**

Now we have that
$(1+\frac{1}{[x]})^{[x]+1}<e*(1+\frac{1}{[x]})<e*(1+\frac{1}{\nu})<(1+\varepsilon)$

On the other side:
$(1+\frac{1}{[x]+1})^{[x]}=(1+\frac{1}{[x]+1})^{[x]+1-1} \ge (e- \varepsilon)*(1+\frac{1}{[x]+1})^{-1} \ge (e- \varepsilon)*(1+\frac{1}{\nu+1})^{-1}=(e- \varepsilon)*(\frac{\nu+1-1}{\nu+1})^{-1}=(e- \varepsilon)*(\frac{\nu+1}{\nu+2})=(e- \varepsilon)*(1-\frac{1}{\nu+2}) \ge (e- \epsilon)*(1- \varepsilon)= e- \varepsilon-e \varepsilon+{\varepsilon}^2 \ge e- \varepsilon-e \varepsilon=e-(1+e)* \varepsilon$

Now we can say that $e-(1+e)* \varepsilon \le (1+\frac{1}{x})^{x} \le e*(1+\varepsilon) $ and then the thesis.

4)**But from this last sentence I can't say that  $e- \varepsilon < (1+\frac{1}{x})^{x} \le e + \varepsilon $**

Comment: Double check what you've written.  You asked for $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{x})^{\color{red}{n}}$ which is distinctly different than $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{x})^{\color{red}{x}}$.  In the first, the exponent does not change, and given any specific value of $n$ the expression $(1+\frac{1}{x})^n$ will eventually approach $1$.  The limit of $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ approaches $e$ as a result of both the terms being multiplied approaching $1$ *and* the exponent approaching infinity at the same time.

Comment: Note that $1\leq (1+\frac{1}{x})^n=1+\frac{n}{x}+\binom{n}{2}\frac{1}{x}^2+\dots+\frac{1}{x^n}<1+\frac{n^n}{x}\to 1$ as $x$ eventually grows much larger than a finite number $n^n$.

Comment: @JMoravitz I edited the text. Can you help me?